# Boost::Spirit. Parse string excluding substrings

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

How to parse a string using boost::spirit excluding defined substrings?

For example, a string must not contain $lf, $pt, $kf

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean?

Comment: for example, a string must not contain $lf, $pt, $kf

Comment: You can (and should) edit your question. Preferrably, before posting it - incomplete questions are useless

Comment: Sorry no! That's just a brazenness of a question ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may mean

```
*(qi::char_ - (qi::lit("$if") | qi::lit("$pt") | qi::lit("$kf"))
```

Comment: why did you use lit here?

Comment: I meant `qi::lit`, fixed. I prefer if my code compiles ([`invalid operands of types ‘const char [...]’ and ‘const char [...]’ to binary ‘operator|’`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b14ef1f9f825cc59)?)

Comment: qi::char_ parses one character. qi::lit("$if") takes a string. how does your code work?

Comment: `*(p)` matches 0 or more repetitions of `p` eagerly (**[documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/kleene.html)**). `(p - q)` matches any input that matches `p` iff it doesn't match `q` (**[documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/difference.html)**).